# SQL Filter by List of ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have three tables

```
1-rests
2-amenity_rest
3-amenities
```

```
rests
id      name
1       rest1
2       rest2
3       rest3

amenities
id     name
1      amenity1
2      amenity2
3      amenity3

amenity_rest
rest_id         amenity_id
1                  1
1                  3
2                  2
3                  1
```

I would like to send a List of amenities like [1,3]

and it should return the rest that its id=1

and if I send array [1,2,3] it should return no result

How would such a query look alike?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support arrays, so your question is not clear.

Comment: I mean array is list of amenities ids

Comment: @ShenoudaShehata why the output for [1,3] should be [1] instead of [1,3]

Comment: I don't get it, I'm guessing here you send the array to the controller which manages to make the query, right? if you send [1,3] shouldn't it return the row with id=2?

Comment: @Tarun because amenities have id [1,3] related to rest 1

Comment: @Gamopo exactly

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this question related to PHP after all, if you haven't written any query yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the query as:

```
select ar.rest_id
from amenity_rest ar
where ar.amenity_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by ar.rest_id
having count(*) = 3;  -- "3" = size of list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should have a function like this:

```
function retrieveData(Request $request){
    $data = Amenities_rest::whereIn('amenity_id', $request->amenities)
                            ->groupBy('rest_id')
                            ->havingRaw('COUNT (*) = ' . count($request->amenities))
                            ->get();
    return $data
}
```

That should do it. I hope it helps.